# How do update to adobe flash 19.0.0.245 or higher

Tags: flash, adobe

Trying to watch the NBC Rio live stream of the olypmics on my laptop, and I get the message that I need Flash Player 19.0.0.245 or higher to watch it.

How do I install the latest version on Ubuntu 14.04?  I've tried the other answers, but none of them work.

Comment: What browser do you use? And please tell us exactly what other answers you already tried, there are tons of advices out there.

Comment: Just install Google Chrome.

Comment: I have Chrome, Firefox, Another version of Chrome, and Vivaldi.  None of them work.   I downloaded the libpepflashplayer.so file from adobe and tried putting it in ~/.mozilla/plugins and /usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins and neither of these options work.  Thoughts?

Comment: use pipelight, described in this thread, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333134 #12 gives command set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: You can't, but...

Long Story:
It depends on your browser.

- Google Chrome: It has a built-in flash plugin and if it's up to date, flash should be up to date.  If, like me, you don't use Chrome that might be a problem.  This plugin in Chrome uses the newer "PPAPI" technology to integrate in the browser.
- Mozilla Firefox: Adobe has discontinued any new versions of NPAPI Flash on Linux since a few years.  The current Flash Plugin for Mozilla Firefox is at 11 and will never get a higher version.  (You can see this for yourself at "[Adobe - Flash Player Test Page](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)".  Now that isn't reason for concern as most sites will work just fine with Flash 11  and Adobe does provide security updates for that version.  That flash plugin is flashplugin-installer.  This plugin uses the old "NPAPI" technology to integrate in the browser.
- Chromium: Since I wanted to be complete and Chromium is the "Open Source version" of Chrome, I'd checked whether it was possible to add flash easily to that browser too.  Seems you can and that the procedure that Selvakumar wrote is the way to go.  There is a [Ubuntu wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash) that describes the actions with screenshots, but the description of Selvakumar is totally accurate.  The only gripe I have is that it shouldn't work for Firefox, but after writing this I will try.  I hope to be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Ok, just to be entirely clear.  You will not get the latest version in Firefox using the procedure from Selvakumar or the wiki entry.  I did the following in order to test this:  `sudo aptitude purge flashplugin-installer`.  This removes the Flash I had installed.  Tested: Firefox does not show flash content.  Then I added to required repository (Canonical Partners) and did `sudo aptitude install adobe-flashplugin`.  This, indeed, causes Flash to work again in Firefox, but it still is the 11 version.

Comment: Hmmm - I have version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) of chrome, but that does not work either.   When I click on live stream I just get a perpetual spinner.

Comment: I can't help with that.  Won't install Chrome.  I have no need for that.  Normally, Google is in charge of updating Chrome, so it's in charge of updating Flash.
What does the Flash Test Page I linked to say?
If that works, and it gives you the correct version number, then the issue is with NBC, or something along the network to its site.  (Firewalls for example, may block UDP traffic and most streaming video goes over UDP... )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox, try the following

1. Open "Software & updates" or run `software-properties-gtk` from terminal
2. Check all options under "Ubuntu Software" tab
3. Run `sudo apt-get update` from terminal followed by `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`
4. Restart Firefox browser if it is already open

You should be all set.

If it works then the credit goes to  "https://askubuntu.com/users/266507/hi-angel"

Comment: Tried it but it's still the 11 version.